# Why is "them" and not "those" correct?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I have been preparing for the SAT, and this question has been confusing me a lot lately.

> Some scissors (A) **are designed** for left-handed use, although most (B) **of them**
>   (C) **sold in** stores (D) **are not** specialized.

When I initially read this sentence, I thought that B was incorrect (of them). I thought that it should have been "of those."

To my surprise, however, there is no error in this sentence.

Why is "of them" correct and when would it be appropriate to use "of those"?

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ "of them" be correct?  Them is a generic term for a plural number of objects.  "Of those" would have been equally valid.

Comment: I suppose either "them" or "those" is *correct*, as far as that goes. Neither is *right*, because the interpreter of the sentence has to wait, unnecessarily, until the end of the sentence to discover the referent of "them" or "those". As phrased, the referent could be scissors or left-handed scissors. The composer of the sentence could've easily obviated that interpretive burden by using "scissors" instead of "of them" or "of those". The gracelessness of the phrasing is further emphasized by the superfluous "sold in stores" (what else?), although that phrase might be okay in some contexts.

Comment: I would use *the ones*, and not either *them* or *those*.

Comment: @Lynn Because _them sold in stores_ is ungrammatical, that simple. You can’t have _them_ as the antecedent to a reduced relative clause, that requires a deictic.

Comment: This is a ridiculous question to put in a SAT. I would agree with you that B is incorrect; but it is a borderline case, which is why it shouldn't be set in an exam.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquest *they* can be deictic. For example, one person says: Have you seen my keys? and they respond with *They are in your apartment*, or *I left them in your apartment*. Or, “I need my keys. May I have them now?” replacing them with *these* or *those* in “May I ... now?” does not fit.

Comment: In “I need my keys. May I have >>these<< or >>those<< ( a deitic ) now? These/those isn’t referential enough that it may or may not be the antecedent to the previous clause, “them” makes this more certain. *them* is usually a referential pronoun to a certain noun and hence “my keys”, while “these” or “those” are deitical and requires a certain context - these/those may be referring to an object that is out of sight and would need a certain context to understand (that is my understanding of deixis). *them* servers a purpose to make it more clearer as to whatever is being referred to.

Comment: What question was being asked about this sentence? Did you have five alternatives from which to pick (A,B,C,D and "No Error") with the question "Locate the error in this sentence"; or was there some other task set?

Comment: @aesking There was a word missing – it should have said “requires a _discourse_ deictic”. Personal pronouns are also deictics, but they are not valid antecedents of reduced relative clauses. Discourse deictics are all demonstratives (and as antecedents for reduced relative clauses, nearly always distal demonstratives).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with you: it should be *those*, because the participial phrase that follows it (*sold in stores*) is of the defining type, and defining phrases are normally not combined with personal pronouns. They can be combined with personal pronouns, but I suspect unusual circumstances are required for that; at least in this case it sounds off to me.

Answer (score 2):

Using "those" would actually convey the meaning, *those scissors designed for left-handed use*.

> **Some scissors are designed for left-handed use**, although most of **those**
>   [=those scissors designed for left-handed use] sold in stores are not
>   specialized.

Sounds like a load of nonsense, uh?

And so, one way to make the sentence logical is to substitute "them" for "those."

> Some **scissors** are designed for left-handed use, although most of **them** [=most of the scissors] sold in stores are not specialized.

Comment: I don't see any reason why *them* would resolve the syntactic ambiguity here. As far as I can tell, the ambiguity is resolved purely through pragmatics, since it's easy to construct a sentence with the same structure that would be parsed differently than how this answer indicates it would: "Some people claim that they've never done anything wrong, but I suspect almost all of them are liars."

Comment: This is incorrect. _Those_ does not refer to left-handed scissors, and _them_ is just completely ungrammatical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquest why is *them* to refer to scissors incorrect? Using *them* is common to refer to multiple inanimate objects as per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/they); definition 1a.

Comment: @aesking Because of the following reduced relative clause; nothing to do with animacy or number. “Them sold in stores are not specialised” is ungrammatical.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Lynn’s comment, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/they)  says under definition of 1a) of the pronoun *they*:

> those ones —used as third person pronoun serving as [the plural of he, she, *or **it***] or referring to a group of two or more individuals not all of the same sex

---

Side note: someone in the comments mentions “As phrased, the referent could be scissors or left-handed scissors”.

It is true that you can use “them/those” as a referent for either scissors and left-handed scissors and it may seem like it could be both at initial glance, I thought so too.

But really [them/those] and if you ignored the debate whether them or those is more acceptable to refer to an inanimate object, whatever pronoun (lets call this pronoun X); pronoun X in this sentence must be referring to *scissors* and not “left-handed scissors” or the OP’s sentence would be a contradiction:

> ! **Some scissors are designed for left-handed use**, although most [ of *them scissors designed for left-handed use* ] **sold in stores are not specialized**
>
> ! **Some scissors are designed for left-handed use**, although most [ of those *scissors designed for left-handed use* ] **sold in stores are not specialized**

Both sentences contradict that “some scissors are designed for left-handed use” “although most of [them/those] **are not specialized**. You can agree the below would be more semantically agreeable:

> [correct] **Some scissors are designed for left-handed use**, although most [ of *those scissors* ] **sold in stores are not specialized**
>
> [correct] **Some scissors are designed for left-handed use**, although most [ of *them scissors* ] **sold in stores are not specialized**